# python string to number list

Tags: python, string, floating

python string contains floating point numbers

`S = "1,2.5,e,3"`

I am trying to convert it to number list by ignoring non-number values.

```
numbers = ' '.join(c for c in S)

numbers_list = []

for x in numbers:
    if x.isdigit():
        numbers_list.append(x)
print(numbers_list)
```

Instead of

```
[1,2.5,3]
```

it is giving me

```
['1', '2', '5', '3']
```

Comment: For starters: `numbers = S.split(',')`.

Answer (score 3):

```py
S = "1,2.5,e,3"

numbers = []
for x in S.split(','):
    try:
        numbers.append(float(x))
    except ValueError:
        pass

print(numbers)
```

Output:
`[1.0, 2.5, 3.0]`

Comment: @RanaZeeshan Cool. Feel free to mark my answer as "accepted" then. :)